# Sending objects to handlebars template page

Tags: express, handlebars.js

New with express and handlebars. I am attempting to send a javascript object and display the values on the page.

Sending the object based on a mysql query:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('dashboard', {myArray: result});
    });
```

Attempting to show the results:

```
<ul class="users">
    {{# each myArray as |val key|}}
        <li>{{val}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My result currently is a list of "Object".

EDIT:

Got it working:

```
<ul class="users">
    {{# each myArray}}
        <li>{{this.username}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I got my code working thanks to you. 
I am fetching my blog result with NodeJS/Mysql at '/ideas/ url with the following code.

```
app.get("/ideas", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render("ideas/index", { myArray: result });
  });
});
```

Then displaying it as follows in Handlebars template:

```
{{#each myArray}}

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{title}} and {{body}}
</div>

{{ else }}

{{/each }}
```